# Migrating Wordpress to HTTPS with redirect 301

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, pagespeed

I just moved my wordpress site to HTTPS on the same server as before, and everything is working right. I set up a redirect 301 rule and got it working, however when checking the "flow" of traffic I noticed that from `http://www.domain` to `https://domain` I have at least two redirects instead of only one. This do not happen from `http://domain` or `https://www.domain` to the same `https://domain` page.

The rule I'm using is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I used [this link to test redirects count](https://varvy.com/tools/redirects/)

My fear is to lose speed and/or rankings of google. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your site url and wp-content (home) url constants in [wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) like so:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com'); 
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
```

(Make sure there are no dupicates of this rule and to add it before the 'stop editing, happy blogging' note in the file. Also, **backup** your old file before changing it.)

I would then suggest to separate your .htaccess rules as your current setup may not survive an update because you've removed the # END WordPress statement, which is required by the WP core if pretty permalinks have been enabled.

```
#REDIRECT TO HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

and directly below that goes standard WordPress part:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is how I've setup many websites and it always works fine, some servers do like them in a different order but it is recommended to first go to https and then serve the WP files, ideally your webserver would be set to only serve your site via https, which would effectively eliminate the need of this workaround:

[HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

Comment: Hi, the wp-config was already set this way (but with https, since I need this version only to work). I tried to change my htaccess following your suggestion but I still have the same problem that count two redirects instead of one only from the `http://www.domain`

Comment: I've updated my answer as it actually said http where it was meant to be https.. sorry for that. I hope now it makes a tad more sense .

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin to do that easily called Really Simple SSL, in my experience i've lost a bit of google rank when i moved to HTTPS but with time you are gonna gain ranking again,

What happens is that all of your positionated links with HTTP will dissapear in google, and then all links HTTPS will appear so is like to have a new website in some way

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use SRDB tool. I don't know if you know it. With this great tool you can globally change urls in your database. Here is link on GitHub  [search replace database](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB). Everytime I migrate WP site with SSL certificate I use this tool and similar code in .htaccess like you wrote. I have HTTP 200 response always with this.
Simply you copy srdb on ftp and run index via browser. You must set your DB connection, and replace all occurrence of old domain with http with new domain with https.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The two redirects are:

Non https www.domain to https www.domain done by the htaccess

www.domain to domain (both https) done by WP.

You should redirect to the non www domain. Add something like this before your redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```